# Android: see images of IP Camera with webview on Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to make an application for Android which I have a ip camera, and I want to do a live view of what the camera captures.
I use a program called Motion, which captures photos. Jpg and then from the browser, e.g. Firefox, entering "**http://ip:port**" may be a live view of what the camera is capturing.
For android I wrote this code:

```
public class WebviewpfcActivity extends Activity {

public WebView wv;
Uri uri;
ContentValues values;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);


    wv.loadUrl("http://myIP:myPort");

}
}
```

It does not work, the screen goes blank, not what you'll be doing it wrong because using a program called "tinycam Monitor" introducing the same IP and same port if it looks the picture!.

Please help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the following line from your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

and also try changing the webview within main.xml to :

```
<WebView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/webview"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Sorry Sergio, that is the manifest, please paste main.xml from the res->layout folder in here :D

Comment: Please try changing layout_height from match_parent to fill_parent

Comment: Sorry RenegadeAndy, I just correct it and added it up. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you also include the manifest now - I think it may have missed something in there!

Comment: Ok - Try my editted answer now! If it works click the tick :)

Comment: RenegadeAndy I don't understand what you mean by the answer: Please try changing layout_height from match_parent to fill_parent.You can explain it better?

Comment: Sorry, but even including the line, to run the application the screen goes blank. :(.  I put the changes "Manifiest.xml" up.

Comment: Strange, I added another bit to my answer, try that?

Comment: No, including the changes of "main.xml" does not work, the screen goes blank and nothing is visible.

Comment: How odd, what happens if you set the loadURL call to go to "http://www.google.co.uk"

Comment: If I set the URL to "google.co.uk" work, but I need see a sequence of images.

Comment: I am so confused - what is the actual problem then? If you go to the url : port on a normal computer browser what do you see?

Comment: In normal browser you can see a sequence of images .jpg like a streamig,you can see an example in youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhUoKjRPV1w

Comment: Ok. Is the website presented with flash? Javascript? Any kind of plugin? Java plugin perhaps?

Comment: I do not know, I thought that with the code I had written would be enough, but I think it takes something more.

Comment: Well you are going to have to pastebin the html of the page you are trying to display on the phone in this case. You need to give more detail if you actually want help...

Comment: I'm trying to display on the phone a sequence of of images .jpg that gives a IP Camera, in normal computer browser you can see this sequence of images and it seems you are looking at what the camera recorded, as the browser displays all the images that the camera issues and looks like a security camera in android.

Comment: Sergio - if you want support - do what you are being asked of you. Pastebin the html from the page you are trying to view on your phone. Otherwise you can forget getting more help here - because we CANNOT help with what we cannot see.

Comment: RenegadeAndy - Sorry if I caused trouble, but I have explained my problem well and will even set an example with a video and I mentioned a program that does what I want to do. I have not made ​​any Pastebin simply asked for help.

Answer (score 1):

if your manifest.xml and layout.xml is coded correctly. In the your activity, you can use your code like as follows:

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
 String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "\t<title></title>\n" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "<img src=\"http://192.168.1.7:8081/\">\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
    String mime = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

As you see, i used my local ip in html like this and it is working good. And i used the motion ip camera in linux os with no problem.